# preg_match_all Problems

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

I'm trying to match a string that contains HTML code that contains parameters to a function in Javascript.

There are several of these functions found in the the string containing the HTML code.

```
changeImg('location','size');
```

Let's say that I want to grab the location within the single quotes, how would I go about doing this? There are more than one instance in the string.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are there ever escaped single quotes in the string?  For example, `'His dog\'s house'`?  If not, this should be simple.  If so, we are in for some fun.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a fairly common question on SO and the answer is always the same: regular expressions are a poor tool for parsing HTML. Use an XML or HTML parser. That's what they're for. Take a look at [Parse HTML With PHP And DOM](http://www.phpro.org/examples/Parse-HTML-With-PHP-And-DOM.html) for an example and [Parsing Html The Cthulhu Way](https://blog.codinghorror.com/parsing-html-the-cthulhu-way/) for a bit of background.

Parsing Javascript is even harder as it can appear inside `<script>` tags and attributes so in the very least you'd need to get every `<script>` tag and parse the contents as well as every element and parse their event handlers (onclick, etc).

I'm reminded of [this quote](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58640/great-programming-quotes/58646#58646):

> "Some people, when confronted with a
>   problem, think "I know, I’ll use
>   regular expressions." Now they have
>   two problems." -- Jamie Zawinski

Comment: That's technically not the rigt quote... but oh well. I forgot where i read that it is a misquote.

Comment: Also: "If all you have is a hammer, everything looks like a nail" anonygrammer.